# Why does my water have a weird smell and taste after installing a new water softener?

Tags: water-softener

Softener was installed per the installation manual.  Bleach was used to sanitize the unit, per the manual.  Added salt to the unit and  ran a regeneration and everything seemed to work as it should. Went thru the cycles, fill, brining, brine rinse, backwash, fast rinse, and waste water was running into my floor drain.  Took about 2 hours.

Checked the water from a faucet, let it run and eventually the smell began and would not go away.  Cold water first, then the hot water too.  Yikes !!  Over the course of the following week or so, I tried to "flush" the unit by a number of regenerations.  One day I used more than 500 gallons (my water company has a method of allowing customers to track our water consumption) of water.  Over 1600 gallons in one week.

I closed the bypass on the unit, drained the water heater, let the cold run for a period of time to clear the bad water.  Been using water that bypasses the softener.  I might add that  the unit was producing soft water during my "testing" of the water.

Searched the Internet for my problem and various sites had info on water smells and taste.  Most had the same questions and answers.  None seemed to fit my situation, except one.  It mentioned the two primary materials that made up resin beads was a type of plastic and a liquid material (DVB) to bond the plastic.  It is a yellow liquid with a STRONG odor !!

They said if, after installing your softener, your water smells worse than before, it's probably the DVB from the resin beads, which can leak into your water supply.

Why would I have bad resin in a new water softener?  They did not seem to have a solution for the resin problem.  I am open to suggestions.   ---Donald---

Comment: Have you contacted the maker/supplier of the water softener?

Comment: If you open the lid on the softener is the smell stronger in the tank?  If so, then it could be time to return it.  Otherwise, sometimes when water flow is changed, if you have a filter before it, as I do coming into the house, the filter will spit out junk and lots of it.  I replaced my filter about 3 months ago and there was about 1 week of junk in lines before it cleared out.